# How to insert a new key value to the existing JSON object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash, javascript-objects

I have the below JSON array,

`const data = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}]`

and I have to insert one more property to each object, and expected result would be like this.

`const data = [{id:1,name:'a',selected:false},{id:2,name:'b',selected:false},{id:3,name:'c',selected:false}]`

I'm trying to achieve this javascript only.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's not JSON... just a normal object literal.

Comment: `data.map(val=> ({...val,selected:false}))`

Comment: I have tried this..

data.map((x)=>{
x['selcted']=false;
})

Answer (score 2):

The question did not reach the standards of Stackoverflow, but from your comments, I believe that you are seriously looking for a solution's than your reputation.

The answer is kind of simple old-school method, please refer and give a try. Thanks.

```js
const data = [{id:1,name:'a',selected:false},{id:2,name:'b',selected:false},{id:3,name:'c',selected:false}]

data.forEach((element,index) => {
    element["selected"] = false,
        element["test"]=index+1 // any key-value pairs
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to React, Actually I have tried this..
const newState = this.state.data.map((x)=>{
x['selected']=false;
})
so the state didn't changed, and newState became undefined.. 
Now I've assigned to another variable, once modified, Now I'm using setState to update the newState.
Thank you so much...

Comment: @Cegone sorry, you mentioned "only JavaScript" so only I posted this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop is all you need.

```
for (let item of data) {
  item.selected = false;
}
```

On each iteration of this loop, `item` becomes the next item from the iterated object (`data`, in this case).  Since the array still references these same objects, you can modify `item`, and this modification also appears on the item in `data`... again because it is the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
   // add the addition property using dot notation
   data[i].selected = 'false';
}

// output to console the updated data
   console.log(data);
```